# Disable ShiftNode of BottomNavigationView in support library 28.0.0

Tags: android, user-interface, bottomnavigationview

After upgrading support library to `v-28.0.0` `BottomNavigationView` shift mode not disabling. Even I am using `app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"` but items are shifting & item text gets cut on selection.

Previously I was using reflections to do this. Is there any other way to disable shift mode.

Comment: How many menu items are there in your BottomNavigationView ?

Comment: @ChintanSoni 5 menu items.

Answer (score 3):

To me, in XML enable the shifting mode used, with match_parent width

```
            app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
```

Disable shifting mode used

```
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

& remove your reflections. Mine works as usual.

Comment: Except that I want labels to show up on tablets where there is room and not show up on phones where there is no room. Otherwise this works great.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help (it's kotlin) :

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
fun disableShiftMode(view: BottomNavigationView) {
    val menuView = view.getChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView
    try {
        val shiftingMode = menuView.javaClass.getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode")
        shiftingMode.isAccessible = true
        shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false)
        shiftingMode.isAccessible = false
        for (i in 0 until menuView.childCount) {
            val item = menuView.getChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView
            item.setShiftingMode(false)
            // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
            item.setChecked(item.itemData.isChecked)
        }
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to get shift mode field")
    } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to change value of shift mode");
    }
}
```

Comment: This method works for only support library below 28.0.0

Comment: you can try using 

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    fun removeShiftMode(view: BottomNavigationView) {
        val menuView = view.getChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView
        menuView.labelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED
        menuView.buildMenuView()
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `app:itemTextAppearanceActive` and `app:itemTextAppearanceInactive` to the same textAppearance style, or ones that have the same `textSize` and `fontFamily`